# Spring JDBC Authentication vs LoadUserByName Differences

Tags: spring, authentication, userdetailsservice

Im new on spring security and I had some research on authentication ,I saw two options there are some guys posted.First one Jdbc authentication or In memory authentication ,and there are also loadUserByName(UserDetailService).
 **what is difference between them ,and also what is use case of loadUserByName** (UserDetailService)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the official reference [https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-authentication](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-authenticationhttp://)

For **In Memory Authentication**, you have a set of username-password pair hard-coded in your xml/java config class.

In **jdbc authentication**, you can have a direct database contact to fetch users and authorities, provided you have configured a `datasource`

You can define custom authentication by exposing a custom **UserDetailsService** as a bean. You can do whatever functionality to return an instance of `UserDetails` in `loadUserByUsername()`. This method is called implicitly to authenticate a user, when creating an authentication.